# How to update DataGridView real time execution?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

My `DataGridView` displays information that is entered on another system. As the user insert, update or delete any information, the `DataGridView` should be updated right now.
I thought about using a recursive method or thread background, but it did not help.
My code is:

```
private void Andon_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadGrid();
}

private void LoadGrid()
{
    DataTableWorkCall cdtwc = new DataTableWorkCall();
    DataTable dtPBList = new DataTable();

    dtPBList = cdtwc.CreatePendingWorkCall();
    DataTableWorkCall.GetDataTableNew = dtPBList;


    if (DataTableWorkCall.GetDataTableNew != DataTableWorkCall.GetDataTableOld)
    {
        if (DataTableWorkCall.GetDataTableNew.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTableWorkCall.GetDataTableOld = DataTableWorkCall.GetDataTableNew;
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            DataView dv = new DataView(DataTableWorkCall.GetDataTableNew);
            dv.Sort = "workCallOpenDate DESC";
            dgvAndon.DataSource = dv;
            lblRefreshDate.Text = "Atualizado em: " + DateTime.Now;
            existData = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

            music.Clear();
            music.StopSound();

            lblRefreshDate.Text = "Atualizado em: " + DateTime.Now;
            existData = false;
        }

        this.Activate();
        //LoadGrid();
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

        lblRefreshDate.Text = "Atualizado em: " + DateTime.Now;
        existData = false;

        LoadGrid();
    }

}
```

This not work´s, can anyone help me?

Comment: you can refresh your grid, after a defined peroid of time, by using `Timer` control

Comment: I need the DataGridView is updated only when there are changes to datatable. Using the timer, even if there is no change the DataGridView will update.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this,(as said by shahid Iqbal) is to use a timer and re-bind your datagridview to the datasource at the specified time interval but then it is possible that user has not changed the related datasource.

But if you want a more robust approach take a look below:

[Real-Time DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869040/real-time-datagridview)

As you see it takes some time to implement this functionality.