# ADO.Net binding table to datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, ado.net

I want to Bind table from SQL database to my datagridview in windows forms c#
and that my datagridview keeps updating it's content like receiving a signal from the database that is the table has been updated so my datagridview download only the new records or update the updated records in the database

it's for CRM system by the way , thanks

Comment: [How to: Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView Control on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869040/real-time-datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a trigger in your Database, triggers are some kind of event that fires when a database table is added/updated/deleted

[SQL Server Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)